# Retrieving all regions as a client cache

Tags: gemfire, geode

I am looking for a way to programmatically retrieve all regions and return the count/size. I can see how gfsh has the "list regions" but can't seem to find the backing java api command. I've tried

```
cache = ClientCacheFactory().addPoolLocator().create();
RegionService regionService =   
clientCache.createAuthenticatedView(properties);
```

but the resulting regionService.rootRegions is empty. I can get query service and run something like "select count(*) from /UserRegion" but would like to dynamically retrieve the regions.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve regions on the server?

Comment: Yes, the regions exist on the server and I am connecting with a client cache through the locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using the MBean is to execute a remote function, something like [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/ListRegionsOnServerFunction.java)

Comment: It sounds like this is the best option if I want to minimize keeping up with connection settings for both the locators and jmx. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of region by Gemfire management service through JMX client.

```
MemberMXBean mbeanProxy =
    (MemberMXBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(
    mbeanServerConnection, mbeanName, MemberMXBean.class, true);
String[] listRegions = mbeanProxy.listRegions();
for (int i = 0; i < listRegions.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(listRegions[i]);
}
```

Comment: What's the proper mbeanName (ObjectName) here?